# MicroStrategy Text Later Dynamic Data

Tags: text, richtext, microstrategy, rich, dossier

How can I call data that will be displayed in Dosier as dynamic data within a Text Layer, so text coming from a database field versus entering the value?

Use case is we have clients where the same value is called two different things, but would like to keep the dossier the same across them, so I can utilize object migration to deploy updates.  I need certain Text layers to display a certain value for one client and another for a different client, though the underlying data the Text label represents would still be called from the same dataset / field.  So purely a semantic layer that allows the label to be different.  The desire is for the Text layer / label to call a field in the DB that has the specific value for the client, so the dossier text layer configuration never changes, just the value it calls changes based on the client stored value in the DB.